# Routing suddenly broke on a KVM guest

Tags: routing, kvm-virtualization

I have a CentOS-based host and a KVM Debian-based virtual machine on it. A host has an Ethernet bridge on its external network interface, this bridge is used by KVM:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:01:5E:92  
          inet addr:5.XX.XX.84  Bcast:5.XX.XX.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:feaf:95b3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2893439068 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2943859744 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3109906781642 (2.8 TiB)  TX bytes:3271403241664 (2.9 TiB)

br0:0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:25:90:01:5E:92  
          inet addr:10.228.0.1  Bcast:10.228.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

The bridge has two IPs, one external and another one from a virtual LAN between the host and the guest. It acts as a default gateway for the guest. STP is turned off on the bridge.

The problem is that the guest got an odd routing rule somehow:

```
root@new:~# ip route get 50.31.164.148
50.31.164.148 via 5.XX.XX.81 dev eth0  src 10.228.0.250 
    cache  ipid 0x0dfb rtt 4.781s rttvar 4.297s ssthresh 7 cwnd 9
root@new:~#
```

`5.XX.XX.81` is a default gateway of the host and I can't find this IP anywhere in static routing tables on the guest:

```
root@new:~# ip route list
default via 10.228.0.1 dev eth0 
10.116.0.0/16 via 10.116.0.146 dev tun0 
10.116.0.146 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.116.0.145 
10.228.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.228.0.250
```

I wonder how this was possible at all and what should we do to prevent situations like this?
Of course, `ip route flush cache` saved us but we definitely want to eliminate problem itself not to blindly flush the routing cache periodically.

Comment: ICMP redirects, http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-icmp.html Your solution is quite unusual, normally one wouldn't bridge to a real interface but setup routing and masquerading on the host.

Comment: @AndreasM Please convert your comment to the answer and I will accept it as a solution, you were absolutely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converting my comment to an answer)

ICMP redirects, see [linux-ip.net/html/routing-icmp.html](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-icmp.html)

Your solution is quite unusual, normally one wouldn't bridge to a real interface but setup routing and masquerading on the host.

Comment: Bridging isn't unusual here. Putting an old-style IP alias on the bridge, in another network, is unusual (and probably wrong).